# Angular displaying data in a deep populated object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

Html

```
<div ng-controller="topicController">
     <a href="#/dashboard">Dashboard</a> | <a href="#/topics">Topics</a> | <a href="#/users">Users</a>

    <h4>{{topic.user_name}} posted a topic</h4>

    <h2>{{topic.topic}}</h2>
    <h4>Description: {{topic.description}}</h4>
    <div ng-controller="postController">
        <label>Post Your Answer here</label>
            <form>
                <textarea name="post" ng-model="new_post.post"></textarea>
                <input type='submit' value='Submit' ng-click='addPost(users._id, topic._id, users.name)'>
            </form>

            <div ng-repeat="x in topic.posts">
                <h4>{{x.post}}</h4>
                <p>Likes:{{x.up_vote}} Dislikes:{{x.down_vote}}</p>
                <ul ng-repeat="i in topic.posts[x].comments">
                    <li>{{topic.posts[x].comments[i].comment}}</li>
                </ul>
                <div ng-controller="commentController">
                <form>
                        <textarea name="comment" ng-model="model.comment"></textarea><br>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="addComment(users._id, x._id, users.name)">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in the image below, I have all the data popualted, the Topic Object, inside topic Posts, & inside posts Comments.

In my my html i can display the topic content & the posts properly, but having difficulty displaying the comments.

The comments are adding to DB but not showing. I have a ng-repeat to itterate through each comment of each post but its just not showing up. Attaching Image to display the entire object in my console.

[image: screenshot]

Is my ng-repeat wrong ?

Comment: Not sure if it is related, but your `post_count` is 0, while you have an array of 3 posts.

Comment: no the post_count is a field i have created, Doesn't have anything to do with the array of posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `x` is a `post` object, not an index. So your inner `ng-repeat` should be

```
<ul ng-repeat="c in x.comments">
    <li>{{c.comment}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I did that and it worked ..

I was under the impression the comments is an array inside the post which itself in an array inside topics so il need to iterate through each post instance inside the topic.

what you did makes so much more sense though.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding what `x` represents inside your `ng-repeat` for the comments. `x` is the actual comment object - each item in the `comments` array on the post. So `topic.posts[x]` makes no sense. It should just be `x`.

So, obviously, rename it to `comment`, instead of `x`.

Bonus tip: always use `track by` with your `ng-repeat` expressions for performance reasons. In your case, it would be `track by comment._id`.

Comment: I did track by _id and it gave me "Error: ngRepeat:dupes
Duplicate Key in Repeater"

change it to track by $index and it works fine. its basically doing the same thing am i right ?

Comment: Not exactly the same thing. What you track by should be a unique property on every item, so you must have duplicate `_id`s (or records without an `_id` property). If you use `track by $index`, and then reorder elements in the list, it won't correctly move the elements around, instead it will change the contents of each element.